# IText5 - different footer on every page

Tags: java, itext, footer

I created an IText5 document in Java:

```
  Document document = new Document();
  PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, pageOut);
  document.open();
```

I am interating through a list of cars and for each of them I create a newPage.
For each `newPage` I want car name in footer. 
I can't find examples for it, I only found how to have the same footer on every page.
I found this example based on events: http://itextpdf.com/examples/iia.php?id=103 but it doesnt seem to be a good solution as I am iterating through cars list and in this approach I cant print car name in footer.

Answer (score 2):

Extend the HeaderFooter class by a member variable currentCar which you set from outside to the car currently processed, and use the content of that member variable in your onEndPage method to generate an appropriate header and footer.

Depending on your control loop you have to take care to properly coordinate the changing of that member and the switching of the page to not be off by one in your headers and footers.